# Select from entities where result equals multiple values from List<T>

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity

Say there is an Object for U.S. Cities

```
public class City
{
    public int Id
    public String State
    public String City
}
```

I have a list of cities and states

```
List<Cities> Cities = new List<Cities>();
Cities.Add(new City { City = "Philadelphia", State = "PA" });
Cities.Add(new City { City = "New York", State = "NY" });
```

I want to search my sql database setup as

```
Id int
City varchar
State varchar
```

To get the Full object, mainly the Ids
I have tried numerous approaches as my latest

```
var results = (from Cities in c.Cities
    where distinctValues.Select(m => 
    m.City).ToList().Contains(Cities.City)                               
    && distinctValues.Select(m => 
    m.State).ToList().Contains(Cities.State)
                           select new City
                           {
                               City = Cities.City,
                               State= Cities.State,
                               Id = Cities.Id
                           }).ToList();
```

give me error for

```
Unable to create a constant value of type.
```

Is there a way to search where a record matches multiple properties in a List object

I'm trying to do what I use to do in creating a sql query which was iterate over every item in the list and add parameters for each such as

```
select Id,City,State FROM Cities WHERE (city = @city1 and state = @state1) or (city = @city2 and state = @state2)
```

where

```
@city1 = philadelphia,@state1 = PA, @city2 = new york and @state2 = ny
```

Comment: Given that many cities exists only in one state, it might be simpler to query all items matching desired cities names and then do additional filtering on client side...  
  
It is hard to understand what you are trying to do with your complex query...

Comment: There are City names in multiple states.  One of the biggest that stands out is Springfield, which is in at least 3 states (PA,IL,OR).

Comment: Essentially I'm matching a file that is being uploaded with cities and states, checking that they exist and grabbing the id to put in another table as the "Location Id", else if it doesn't exist, notify user that there was something possibly incorrect

Comment: I am not sure if it would work but adding a computed column that would return something like state + "§" + city and then do usual request with Contains might also works. In any case, you have to validate the performance of the request. Sometimes, it is more efficient to do part of the request on client side or to do a few simple requests than a big one.